# How can I add values to an AngularJS <select> without changing the data source?

Tags: angularjs

I have coded the following:

```
<select
    data-ng-disabled="!option.selectedSubject"
    data-ng-model="option.selectedContentStatus"
    data-ng-options="item.id as item.status for item in option.contentStatuses">
    <option style="display: none" value="">Select Content Status</option>
</select>
```

This give me a list of statuses for me to select from.  However I would like to add one addition to the list with a value of "99" and a name of "All". To do this I tried:

```
<select
    data-ng-disabled="!option.selectedSubject"
    data-ng-model="option.selectedContentStatus"
    data-ng-options="item.id as item.status for item in option.contentStatuses">
    <option style="display: none" value="">Select Content Status</option>
    <option value="99">All</option>
</select>
```

But this does not work. All I see is the Select Content Status and the additional option 99 All does not appear.

Is there any way I can make it possible for this additional option without making a change to the array option.contentStatuses?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an ng-repeat on the options you want generated via data next to static option values within the select:

```
<select ng-model="option.selectedContentStatus">
    <option value="">Select Content Status</option>
    <option value="99"> All </option>
    <option ng-repeat="item.id as item.status for item in option.contentStatuses" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.status}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The only thing I see are the "Select Content Status" and All. I'm trying to look into this now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a directive that will add that extra "All" option to the drop-down.

The html:

```
<select add-option-all
    data-ng-disabled="!option.selectedSubject"
    data-ng-model="option.selectedContentStatus"
    data-ng-options="item.id as item.status for item in option.contentStatuses">
    <option style="display: none" value="">Select Content Status</option>
</select>
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('addOptionAll',
   function($timeout) {
      return {
         link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // use $timeout if you want to add "All" at the bottom else dont use                
            $timeout(function(){
                element.append("<option value='99'>All</option>");
            }, 1000);
       }
   };
});
```